# Include Specific Foreign Keys in DRF Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-key-relationship

Here's two simple models to use as an example:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True, )

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Now what I'd like to do, is create a view for `Book` that pulls in one of the values from `Author` using the Django Rest Framework. Here's an example `ModelSerializer`:

```
class BookMetaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ('title','date','author__name',)
```

The trouble is that one can't access the fields of a foriegn key in the DRF like I gave above `author__name`. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this based on the documentation. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **define `author_name` field with `source` argument** to get the name of an author.

From the DRF docs on [`source` argument:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments)

> The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field. May
>   be a method that only takes a `self` argument, such as
>   `URLField('get_absolute_url')`, or **may use dotted notation to traverse
>   attributes**, such as `EmailField(source='user.email')`.

**Final Code:**

```
class BookMetaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # use dotted notation to traverse to 'name' attribute       
    author_name = serializers.CharField(source='author.name', read_only=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title','date','author_name',)
```

Comment: omg! Thank you so much! That's it! Why was that so hard to find?

Comment: Check this docs link. This might help. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments